# How to compile JavaScript files with npm and use in static HTML website?

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules

Now there are so many question but none explicitly tell how to compile JavaScript files with npm and use in static HTML website?

Now [Getting Started](https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) page of MaterializeCss it says I can use it like this to install materilzecss

```
npm install materialize-css@next
```

Now I know this it'll install it but what I don't get is what next step it use in static HTML website?

For the past two years I've been using full path to include in HTML file like this

```
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Bad thing about this is I won't ever use every module in this package. so I'm loading huge extra useless chunk in browser. I need to shrink it as much as possible

I've two environment development and production.
How can I use npm specific module in package to run without compile in local development environment, so I don't have to compile it every time?
And how can I compile and use npm specific module in package, so I don't load extra chunk?

There is a lot of answer saying in index.js use require jquery and done but it doesn't tell how to use index.js, like is it a node js file? do I have to compile it so It include all modules? can I insert index.js in script tag? will it load require in browser?

All I want it simple is to use specific modules of packages and compile it in single file and include in script tag to load in browser and in other script tags I write my custom scripts in production environment, and in development without compilation. I've seen people do it in live projects but couldn't figure it out how it's done, even after extensive research.

Comment: That last paragraph makes it sound like you're after a module bundler.

Comment: I'm not after any module bundler. I just need proper instructions of using npm for static HTML website. Both in production and development environment

Comment: I'm waiting for another day to apply bounty. I really really need to know. It's not like you can only use npm packages for nodejs.

Comment: I found an answer on stackoverflow few days ago. I don't have a link now, it stated that you can't use bower for these things because it can't compile and for that we have use npm. I'm looking for proper way

Comment: Sorry, in that case I haven't understood your question. Before applying a bounty, I'd recommend you rephrase it to make it clear what you are asking.